# Google not saving the correct password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Firstly I should probably ask if saving passwords to Google Chrome is the same thing as saving them to your Google Account.  Just recently there is a different window that pops up for saved passwords.  It use to notify you that you were saving them to Chrome.  Now it says it's saving it to my google account.  But it automatically enters the incorrect information.  I've gone into the setting on chrome and turned offer to save passwords of and then on again.  I've made certain that Chrome is up to date.  It still does it. It's a funny looking window with the icon of a key on it.  Is there anyway to fix this problem?  I don't know much about computer stuff so...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, saving passwords to Google Chrome (client side, browser) and saving password for the google account (server side, service) are two different things.

According to [Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), here is how you can see or delete the passwords saved in Google Chrome:

1. Open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click Profile and then Passwords.

   - See: To the right of the website, click Show password Preview. If you lock your computer with a password, you'll be prompted to enter your computer password.
   - Remove: To the right of the website, click More and then Remove.